# Javascript working only locally, not after hosting the application

Tags: javascript, c#

I want a popup to be shown and then page to be redirected to another one on click of the button. The webpage is developed in C#. I have written following code which is working fine when I run the application locally. But when it is hosted the popup is not getting displayed though the page is getting redirected.

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "SomeAction", "alert('Action SUCCESSFUL'); window.location='" + VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(Request.Path) + "MyPage.aspx';", true);
```

Comment: Sounds like a Pop Up blocker.

Comment: I think popup blocker settings are set at browser level, is it set at server level as well? I am viewing in the same browser.

Comment: Depending on browser it is domain/security level. And you might not realize on your development location you approved pop ups at sometime. BUT what you are seeing is normally a pop up blocker blocking alerts that fire on load of the page.

Comment: @UserM - indeed, but different sites endup in different "zones". Localhost is generally "intranet" with less restrictions, "hosted sites" are generally "internet" with most restrictions.

Comment: I have similar functionality on another page, that only has to display an alert message, which is getting displayed. On this screen I need to redirect to another page after the popup. I feel I am missing something in the code .